# Error al compilar proyecto angular - cannot run Angular project (version mismatch, thread id/fibers, etc.)

Tags: nodejs, angular, angular-cli

Hace poco cloné un proyecto Angular y sin hacer más modificaciones que el npm install descubrí que no compilaba. He pasado por una serie de errores que me llevaron a **hacer coincidir las versiones local y global de angularCLI..**
[image: ng version de cmd]

[image: ng version dentro del proyecto]

**También eliminé fibers**, que me ocasionaba un error de *thread_id* y que luego al hacer *ng serve* muestra una serie de errores "..has no exported member".

[image: Ng serve no exported member]

He eliminado y vuelto a instalar el node modules también.

Probando suerte con *npm ls @angular/core* encontré esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que probablemente hay alguna dependencia/version que no supe ver bien.

PD: aquí va el package.json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de usar `ng serve` ¿Intentaste ejecutarlo desde el primer momento con `npm start`? El problema con `ng serve` es que utiliza la versión global que tienes instalada en tu máquina y ahí es cuando empiezan los problemas. Intenta clonar el proyecto de nuevo, darle `npm install` y luego simplemente `npm start`.

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta. Sí, tambien he probado. Sale el error de has no exported members y otros de node modules

Comment: trataste de eliminar archivo `node_modules` ?y luego hacer un npm install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm rebuild` parece haber puesto todo en su lugar.

Comment: Elimina tanto de tu pregunta como de tu respuesta las secciones en inglés. Son innecesarias, ¡estamos en [es.so]! El idioma oficial del sitio es el español.